# How can I optimize the js size of my AngularDart application?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have read [the Chapter on *Production Deployment*](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/09-ch07-deploying-your-app.html) of the angular tutorial which indicates several ways to optimize the JS output size.

I also see a commit named  [feat(transformers): Add angular transformers to pub for no-mirror code generation](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/commit/3fb218180b17bdc9808e575e3a9aaf9928fef28b). In this commit we can see the use of a new *angular* transformer.

1. Will this new transformer make the advices of the Angular tutorial obsolete ?
2. Will the optimization process be as simple as adding a single transformer to the pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: This is my understanding too, but I'm not sure either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes.

The tutorial should be updated with the next AngularDart release.

You can try out the transformers now by referencing the github repo in your pubspec.yaml.